# Oracle Regex to remove small words

Tags: regex, string, oracle11g

I am trying to scrub some address catalog which was originally user input for later processing.  Having removed numbers and special characters, now I have strings like:

```
ST SOMETHING SOMEWHERE H BL D S
```

So, `ST` stands for street, `H` house and so on.. Not trying to be super precise here, so I figured just removing anything under 3 chars would be enough for now, but I can't seem to find the correct regexp in Oracle. Have tried:

```
SELECT
    regexp_replace('ST SOMETHING SOMEWHERE H BL D S','[\ ^]\w{1,3}[\ $]', ' ')
FROM dual;
```

which yields:

```
ST SOMETHING SOMEWHERE BL S
```

and I wish I had only

```
SOMETHING SOMEWHERE
```

could someone lend me a hand?

(I'm on oracle 11g)

Comment: I don't remember the exact syntax of Oracle's regex replace functions, but I think you want a global replace.

Comment: while is does have a cheat sheet defining global replace ( http://psoug.org/snippet/Regular-Expressions--Regexp-Cheat-Sheet_856.htm ) REGEXP_REPLACE doesn't seem to accept this parameter ( http://docs.oracle.com/cd/B19306_01/server.102/b14200/functions130.htm )

Answer (score 0):

try

```
SELECT
  regexp_replace(
      '<raw string>'
     ,'(^|[[:space:]])([^[:space:]]{1,3}[[:space:]]+)*[^[:space:]]{1,3}([[:space:]]|$)'
     , ' '
  )
FROM dual;
```

hope that will suit your needs, regards, carsten